# jQuery Validate - resetForm() Not Behaving as Expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Site in question is http://epraxadev.com/kw/palisade-palms/

"Click here for brochure" and "Learn More about Palisade Palms" both bring up a lightbox with the same HTML form to be filled out...the "learn more..." link also changes some of the HTML in the form (the value for a hidden form field, and the fields required).

I'm using Colorbox for the lightbox, and for its onClosed event, I have this to reset the form:

```
onClosed: function() {
        $('#brochure-form label em').remove();
        $('#brochure-form').data('validator').resetForm();
    }
```

Now here's the problem:

- User tries to submit the "brochure" form, but it fails validation. User closes the lightbox.
- User opens up the "Learn more" lightbox, and tries to submit the form...now, instead of using the correct validation rules (only requiring e-mail and referrer), it requires all fields to be filled out (as is the case with the "Brochure Form")

Is there something that I can add to the onClosed function, to clean up all the validation rules?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by manually adding & removing the "required" class to desired inputs during the onComplete and onClosed colorbox events, respectively.

Before, I was adding the required input rules with

```
$('#brochure-form').validate({
            rules: {
                first_name: "required",
                last_name:  "required",
                email: "required",
                phone: "required",
                address: "required",
                city: "required",
                state: "required",
                zip: "required",
                referrer: "required"
            }
        });
```

And those rules weren't properly cleaned out with the resetForm() function.

You can see the working code at http://epraxadev.com/kw/palisade-palms/

You can see the old, non-working version at http://epraxadev.com/kw/palisade-palms/test.html

Comment: Actually, I guess it's not the resetForm() function's responsibility to clean out the validation rules. I just have a really weird case (I  know, I tried to convince the client not to use the same damn form twice, please give the user ANOTHER option besides that same form, sheesh)